# Is there any method to Get all Flags that are not of a type in FlagsAttributed enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a field in Db that maps to enum with flagsattribute. Now i have to filter out results on the basis of this field .
 Say I have a color table with a field called value that is mapped to below enum.

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum Colors
{
    None = 0,
    Red = 1,
    Black = 2,
    Green = 4
}

//I want to achieve sth like this.
//Is there any equivalent of this in c#??
Colors[] colorsTharAreNotGreen=Colors.OfNotType<Colors.Green>

   var colorsTharAreNotGreenFilter=int[colorsTharAreNotGreen.Length];
   for(int i=0;i<colorsTharAreNotGreen.Length;i++){
       colorsTharAreNotGreenFilter[i]=(int)colorsTharAreNotGreen[i];
    }
   //Later on i want to construct query like
      var query= @"select * from colors
      where value not in(" + String.Join(",",colorsTharAreNotGreenFilter) +")"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to query colors where the Green flag bit is not set, using the bitwise AND operator should do the trick:

```
var query= @"select * from colors
where (value & " + (int)Colors.Green + ") = 0";
```